# Google Container Engine (Kubernetes) and OAuth2 Callback

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-oauth

I am deploying the sample bookshelf node app (https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/tutorials/bookshelf-on-container-engine). This app does OAUTH2 callback.

My question is where do I get the IP Address of the Load Balancer and does it change every time I push a new docker image?
Can I specify a DNS Entry for the LB and use that to register in the Google Oauth2 callback.

```
  "OAUTH2_CALLBACK": "http://<service ip address>/auth/google/callback",
```

Here is my service.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bookshelf-frontend
  labels:
    app: bookshelf
    tier: frontend
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: http-server
  selector:
    app: bookshelf
    tier: frontend
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you already have kubectl configured to access your cluster, you should be able to find the ip address of the service with:

```
$ kubectl get services
```

A [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) is separate from actual [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/). The cluster-ip of the service will not change unless you make changes to the Service.

If you are accessing a service internally, you can specify the service name rather than cluster-ip address.

E.g,

```
$ kubectl get services
NAME                      CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      AGE
elasticsearch             10.3.247.13    <none>           9200/TCP                     9d
```

A deployment config accessing this service:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    }
}
```

Comment: I would need the external service /dns name to provide to the OAuth2 provider.  Do I provide the DNS name in the service.yaml or do I have to make the CNAME entry in my DNS provider? Or does Google Container Engine has a DNS Service?

Comment: If you have exposed your service externally, there will be an EXTERNAL-IP associated with said service. Regarding DNS, as far as I'm aware Kubernetes only handles internal DNS like above